# Ubuntu upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04

Is it possible to upgrade from version 12.04 to 14.04 without uninstalling the former one?

Comment: yep, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

if you upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 then 12.04 will be gone, but your files and settings will be saved as when you do an upgrade of any sort.

But if you wish to save 12.04 then you need to install 14.04 as a fresh install and dual boot it with 12.04. choose dual boot in the installer, it's the same procedure as if you would dual boot any system eg, Windows, Mac or other linux system.

14.04 can have a lot of bugs as it's a new release but they will be fixed over time.

comment if you are unsure of what I mean or have any questions! :)